Number of roots of a quadratic form over GF(2)
If $Q(x) = x^T A x$ with $x \in GF(2)^n$ and $A \in GF(2)^{n \times n}$, is there a way to find how many roots $Q(x)$ has based on any properties of $A$ (e.g., rank, etc.)?

You can express this quadratic form as a sum of guys like  $u^2$, $uv$, $u^2+uv+v^2$ for linearly independent linear forms $u, v$

And how would that help me to find how many roots the quadratic form has?

@FabioDias If $Q(x)$ can be written as a sum of $\sum_{i=1}^{d} Q_i(x)$ where each $Q_i(x)$ only depends on a (different) subset of the variables of the original $Q$, then the value distribution of $Q(x)$ becomes the convolution of the value distribution of the $Q_i$-s. So one first solves the problem for the easy forms $u^2$, $uv$ and $u^2+uv+v^2$, and then performs the required convolution.

(I assume you mean roots over $\mathbb{F}_2$.) This was done by Carlitz in the paper "Gauss sums over finite fields of order $2^n$" (Acta Arith. 15, 247-265 (1969)).
Let $r \ge 1$ be the rank of $A$ (which we shall also call the rank of $Q$). We say that $A$ is nonsingular, or that $Q$ is nondegenerate, if $r=n$.
Carlitz showed that the number of zeros is $2^{n-1}$ when $r$ is odd, and is $2^{n-1} \pm 2^{n-\frac{r}{2}-1}$ when $r$ is even. The sign genuinely depends on $Q$.
Below are the details. Let us first suppose that $A$ is nonsingular.
If $n$ is odd there are $2^{n-1}$ zeros. See equation (5.9)' in Carlitz with $q=2$, itself a special case of his Theorem 9. This is proved using the fact, that Carlitz attributes to Dickson, that $Q$ must be equivalent to the quadratic form $\sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} x_{2i-1}x_{2i}+x_n^2$. This is related to the comment of Fedor Petrov. We say $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are equivalent if $Q_1(Mx)=Q_2(x)$ for some nonsingular $M$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
If $n$ is even there are two cases. We say that $Q$ has type $\tau=1$ if it is equivalent to the quadratic form $\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}x_{2i-1}x_{2i}$. We say that it has type $\tau=-1$ if it is equivalent to the quadratic form $\sum_{i=1}^{(n-2)/2}x_{2i-1}x_{2i} + x_{n-1}^2+x_{n-1}x_n+x_n^2$. When $n$ is even, any nonsingular quadratic form over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in $n$ variables is equivalent to exactly one of these two (this is due to Dickson as well).
The result when $n$ is even is that the number of zeros of $Q$ is
$$2^{n-1} + 2^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\tau,$$
see equation (5.7)' in Carlitz with $q=2$, itself a special case of his Theorem 8. This is again proved using Dickson's result.
Carlitz proved these results by computing the exponential sum $\sum_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{F}_2^n}(-1)^{Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}$. This is a good idea because this is a Fourier coefficient of the distribution of $Q$, and it behaves well with respect to convolution, and we already represent $Q$ as a sum of smaller 'independent' quadratic forms, thanks to Dickson's results.
To treat singular $A$, just transform $A$ into an appropriate form - this is explained in page 255 of Carlitz. In detail, let $r$ be the rank of $A$. Then one can prove that $Q(x)$ is equivalent to $Q_2(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$ for some nondegenerate $Q_2$. If $r$ is odd, the number of zeros of $Q(x)$ is $2^{n-r}$ (coming from the variables $x_{r+1},\ldots,x_n$ not influencing the value of $Q_2$) times $2^{r-1}$ (the number of zeros of $Q_2(x)$ as in the odd case), so $2^{n-1}$ zeros in total. If $r$ is even, the number of zeros is $2^{n-r}$ times $(2^{r-1}+2^{\frac{r}{2}-1}\tau)$, so $2^{n-1}+2^{n-\frac{r}{2}-1}\tau$ zeros in total. Here $\tau$ is the type of $Q_2$.
For nonsingular $A$, these results also appear as Theorems 6.30 and 6.32 in the book "Finite Fields" by Lidl and Niederreiter (2nd edition).

That is fantastic, thank you very much! I’ve been searching for this result the whole day and could not find it, you made my day! :) And is there any literature about how to find these zeros or about any properties of the set of zeros of $Q(x)$? Again, thank you!

it's been understood by group theorists considerably earlier, tthat for even n there are two types of othrogonal groups over GF(2) preserving a non-degenerate quadratic form. Two types are distinguished by the dimension of the maximal totally isotropic subspace (either n/2 (so-called '+'  type, or n/2-1 ('-' type)). The '+' type is equivalent, after a base change, to $x_1 x_n + x_2 x_{n-1}+...+x_{n/2-1} x_{n/2}$.
